# Maven including unfiltered resource file in jar rather than what is in target/classes

Tags: maven, resources, properties, jar, filtering

Given,

Apache Maven 3.0.3 and a src/main/resources/application.properties file with

```
 project.root=${basedir}
```

and a pom.xml file with

```
<build>
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
   </resources>
...
```

When I run "mvn clean package", I get a target/classes/application.properties file with filtering

```
project.root=/path/to/MyProject
```

However, the application.properties file that is included in the jar **has not been filtered.**

```
project.root=${basedir}
```

Why is the application.properties file that is included in the jar not filtered? According to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files), the filtered properties file(s) from target/classes ought to be included in the jar.

Comment: I tested this out as you described it and it works for me. Strange. Have you configured the maven-jar-plugin in your pom.xml? If so I would like to see that.

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminLinus.  For my setup, the problem was in the configuration of the maven-bundle-plugin.  I needed to add `<Include-Resources>{maven-resources}</Include-Resources>`.

Comment: I have not using maven-bundle-plugin, but problem exists in multi module maven project.
resources:resources produce filtered file, but clean package produce jar with unfiltered file!
Is any idea how to overcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-service.

Needed to add `<Include-Resources>{maven-resources}</Include-Resources>`
to configuration of [maven-bundle-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22maven-bundle-plugin%22).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                <instructions>
                    <Include-Resources>{maven-resources}</Include-Resources>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Export-Package>${bundle.namespace}.*;version="${project.version}"</Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for making this post, bob.  My solution looked a little different, perhaps because I am using a later version of the plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <!--
      The plugin must be instructed to retrieve the filtered files from the "target/classes" directory.
      Otherwise, it will copy the unfiltered versions in "src/main/resources" to the JAR.
      -->
      <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}, {filtered-file.properties=target/classes/filtered-file.properties}</Include-Resource>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```